# Application connectivity between devices

Tags: android, connectivity

I have my app installed on two devices and I was wondering how could I connect my app on my first device to the app on the other device so that I could send for example a text message which will be displayed in a text view on the second device. It is something like a chat app on a small scale. I just want to have something like "Device no.1 send you this message" and then the message be displayed in a text view. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview

Comment: [Connecting Devices Wirelessly](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/index.html)